# перебор массива обьектов на js

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

подскажите как можно перебрать такой массив на js

```
[Data
    {
        id=3, 
        name='test_1', 
        duration=60, 
        level=3,     
        country=Country{
            id=1, 
            name='Russia',      
            countryCode='RU'
        },
        images=[
            Media{
                id=101, 
                folder=Folder{
                    id=1, 
                    name='quest_images'
                }, 
                name='1.jpg', 
                fileName='img-1499215567399.jpg'
            }, 
            Media{
                id=102, 
                folder=Folder{
                    id=1, 
                    name='quest_images'
                }, 
                name='2.jpg', 
                fileName='img-1499215574221.jpg'
            }
        ]
    }, 
Data
    {
        id=4, 
        name='test_2', 
        duration=20, 
        level=1,     
        country=Country{
            id=1, 
            name='Russia',      
            countryCode='RU'
        },
        images=[
            Media{
                id=101, 
                folder=Folder{
                    id=1, 
                    name='quest_images'
                }, 
                name='1.jpg', 
                fileName='img-1499215567399.jpg'
            }, 
            Media{
                id=102, 
                folder=Folder{
                    id=1, 
                    name='quest_images'
                }, 
                name='2.jpg', 
                fileName='img-1499215574221.jpg'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

или как достать из первого обьекта id=3, name='test_1' и из второго обьекта id=4, name='test_2'?

Comment: что это за "Data" вначале и по середине массива?

Comment: могу ошибаться, но кажется у вас массив с ошибкой,  так же ключи объектов не правильно записанны

Comment: DATA это получается обьект который достаю таким образом
var array =  $('#data-array').attr("value");

Comment: в массиве таких записей делать нельзя, просто объекты, или переменные без названия

Comment: массив не я создавал точнее не вручную

Comment: и свойства объектов назначаются через двоеточие :
name:'2.jpg';

Comment: Скиньте его в json

Comment: подскажите как?

Comment: подскажите что именно значит "достать"? записать куда-то?

Comment: и нужно ли все свойства доставить или только эти ?

Comment: только эти id=3, name='test_1' и из второго обьекта id=4, name='test_2'

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно использовать замыкание. В примере, функция `eachObject` принимает в качестве аргумента объект и перебирает его свойства. На каждой итерации функция проверяет, не является ли свойство объектом? Если является, функция вызывает сама себя и передает в качестве аргумента это свойство. Иначе функция просто выводит в консоль полученное свойство.

```js
 var obj = {
  name : 'object',
  type : 'object',
  props : {
   prop1 : '123',
   prop2 : 'abc'
  }
 }

 var eachObject = function(obj){
  for (key in obj) {
   if( typeof(obj[key]) === 'object' ){
    eachObject(obj[key]);
   } else {
    console.log(key);
   }
  }
 };

 eachObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте етим циклом, если я првильно понял:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
  alert(array[i].id + ' ' + array[i].name);
  alert(array[i].id + ' ' + array[i].name);
}
```

если масив правильно построен должно работать и выводить эти свойства
(вместо array - название вашего массива)

```js
var array = [{
  id: 3,
  name: 'test',
},
{
  id: 4,
  name:'test2',
}
]
for(var i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
  alert(array[i].id + ' ' + array[i].name);
}
```

Comment: пробовал таким образом не работает
пишет "undefined undefined"

Comment: тогда покажите как создается ваш массив

Comment: данные достаются из бд с помощью hibernate и данные передаются в js
а в js забираю уже так 
var array = $('#data-array').attr("value");

Comment: а когда алертом вывожу array то отображается такой массив как указан в первом посте

Comment: такой масив не приемлим

Comment: его нужно переписать) убрать даты и другое, вместо "=" надо поставить ":"

Comment: ну вообщем как у меня в ответе должен выглядеть массив по синтаксису

Comment: а преобразовать его можно как то средствами js в нужный вид?

Comment: ну это скорее всего будет лютый треш если честно, либо я просто не знаю корректных методов для такого. никогда с такими масивами не сталкивался)
невозможно на стороне бд просто нормально переписать?

Comment: возможно можно на стороне java его в json перегнать, а после передать в js

Comment: тогда переганяйте а в js применяйте var jsArray =  JSON.parse(array(тот что с джави)); 
выведите алертом новый масив и посмотрите что покажет